# Expand/Collapse feature not working sidebar (only desktop)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, frontend, tailwind-css

The Expand/Collapse feature is working perfectly on mobile but not working correctly on desktop. This code was originally from ReactJS and I incorporated it to NextJS. It's using tailwind for CSS

I tried to fix it but ended just breaking the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import SidebarLinkGroup from './SidebarLinkGroup';
import SearchModal from '../components/ModalSearch';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'



function Sidebar({ sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  console.log(pathname)
  const trigger = useRef(null);
  const sidebar = useRef(null);

  const storedSidebarExpanded = localStorage.getItem('sidebar-expanded');
  const [sidebarExpanded, setSidebarExpanded] = useState(storedSidebarExpanded === null ? false : storedSidebarExpanded === 'true');
  const [searchModalOpen, setSearchModalOpen] = useState(false);

  // close on click outside
  useEffect(() => {
    const clickHandler = ({ target }) => {
      if (!sidebar.current || !trigger.current) return;
      if (!sidebarOpen || sidebar.current.contains(target) || trigger.current.contains(target)) return;
      setSidebarOpen(false);
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });

  // close if the esc key is pressed
  useEffect(() => {
    const keyHandler = ({ keyCode }) => {
      if (!sidebarOpen || keyCode !== 27) return;
      setSidebarOpen(false);
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyHandler);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('sidebar-expanded', sidebarExpanded);
    if (sidebarExpanded) {
      document.querySelector('body').classList.add('sidebar-expanded');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('sidebar-expanded');
    }
  }, [sidebarExpanded]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Sidebar backdrop (mobile only) */}
      <div
        className={`fixed inset-0 bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-30 z-40 lg:hidden lg:z-auto transition-opacity duration-200 ${
          sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0 pointer-events-none'
        }`}
        aria-hidden="true"
      ></div>

      {/* Sidebar */}
      <div
        id="sidebar"
        ref={sidebar}
        className={`flex flex-col absolute z-40 left-0 top-0 lg:static lg:left-auto lg:top-auto lg:translate-x-0 h-screen overflow-y-scroll lg:overflow-y-auto no-scrollbar w-64 lg:w-20 lg:sidebar-expanded:!w-64 2xl:!w-64 shrink-0 bg-slate-800 p-4 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out ${
          sidebarOpen ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-64'
        }`}
      >
        {/* Sidebar header */}
        <div className="flex justify-between mb-10 pr-3 sm:px-2">
          {/* Close button */}
          <button
            ref={trigger}
            className="lg:hidden text-green-500 hover:text-green-500"
            onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(!sidebarOpen)}
            aria-controls="sidebar"
            aria-expanded={sidebarOpen}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Close sidebar</span>
            <svg className="w-6 h-6 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M10.7 18.7l1.4-1.4L7.8 13H20v-2H7.8l4.3-4.3-1.4-1.4L4 12z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          {/* Logo */}
        </div>

        {/* Links */}
        <div className="space-y-8">
          {/* Pages group */}
          <div>
            <h3 className="text-xs uppercase text-green-500 font-semibold pl-3">
              <span className="hidden lg:block lg:sidebar-expanded:hidden 2xl:hidden text-center w-6" aria-hidden="true">
                •••
              </span>
              <span className="lg:hidden lg:sidebar-expanded:block 2xl:block">CScore.</span>
            </h3>
            <ul className="mt-3">
              {/* Favorites */}
              <li className={`px-3 py-2 rounded-sm mb-0.5 last:mb-0 ${pathname === ('favorites') && 'bg-slate-900'}`}>
                <Link
                  
                  href="/favorites"
                  className={`block text-slate-200 truncate transition duration-150 ${
                    pathname === ('favorites') ? 'hover:text-slate-200' : 'hover:text-white'
                  }`}
                >
                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <svg className="shrink-0 h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        className={`fill-current ${pathname === ('favorites') ? 'text-green-500' : 'text-green-500'}`}
                        d="M12 3.08l1.54 4.478h3.946l-3.178 2.31 1.54 4.478-3.934-2.918-3.934 2.918 1.54-4.478-3.178-2.31h3.946L12 3.08zm0-2.08l-3.932 11.395-9.068.605 8.137 6.01L3.58 24l8.398-5.052 8.136 6.01-1.224-8.92 8.137-6.01H13.93L12 1z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    <span className="text-sm font-medium ml-3 lg:opacity-0 lg:sidebar-expanded:opacity-100 2xl:opacity-100 duration-200 text-green-500">Favoritos</span>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className={`px-3 py-2 rounded-sm mb-0.5 last:mb-0 ${pathname === ('search') && 'bg-slate-900'}`}>
                <button
                  className={`block text-slate-200 truncate transition duration-150 ${
                    pathname === ('search') ? 'hover:text-slate-200' : 'hover:text-white'
                  }`}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    setSearchModalOpen(true);
                  }}
                  aria-controls="search-modal"
                >
                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <svg className="shrink-0 h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      {/* Magnifying Glass icon */}
                      <path
                        className={`fill-current ${pathname === ('search') ? 'text-green-500' : 'text-green-500'}`}
                        d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27c1.09-1.32 1.75-3.01 1.75-4.73C16.18 4.01 14.17 2 11.75 2S7.32 4.01 7.32 6.99c0 1.72.66 3.41 1.75 4.73l-.28.27H8.5l4 4L17 14.01l-1.5-.01zm-3.75-1c-1.93 0-3.5-1.57-3.5-3.5S9.82 6 11.75 6s3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5S13.68 13 11.75 13z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    <span className="text-sm font-medium ml-3 lg:opacity-0 lg:sidebar-expanded:opacity-100 2xl:opacity-100 duration-200 text-green-500">Procurar Jogos</span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </li>
              {/* Utility */}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Expand / collapse button */}
        <div className="pt-3 hidden lg:inline-flex 2xl:hidden justify-end mt-auto">
          <div className="px-3 py-2">
            <button onClick={() => setSidebarExpanded(!sidebarExpanded)}>
              <span className="sr-only">Expand / collapse sidebar</span>
              <svg className="w-6 h-6 fill-current sidebar-expanded:rotate-180" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path className="text-green-500" d="M19.586 11l-5-5L16 4.586 23.414 12 16 19.414 14.586 18l5-5H7v-2z" />
                <path className="text-green-500" d="M3 23H1V1h2z" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <SearchModal id="search-modal" searchId="search" modalOpen={searchModalOpen} setModalOpen={setSearchModalOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Is it a responsive design problem? What could be causing this?

Comment: How is the Expand/Collapse not working correctly on desktop? How is this component incorporated into the rest of the project? It seems to have props but you have omitted any details about what passes the props.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're conditionally hiding the expand/collapse button on larger screens using CSS classes, specifically hidden `lg:inline-flex 2xl:hidden`. These classes are controlling the visibility of the button on different screen sizes.

The classes `hidden` and `lg:inline-flex` are responsible for hiding the button on larger screens (desktops), but the class `2xl:hidden` could be causing the issue because it is hiding the button on 2xl screens as well, which I think is causing the expand/collapse button to be hidden on all screen sizes.

Try this:

```
{/* Expand / collapse button */}
<div className="pt-3 hidden lg:inline-flex justify-end mt-auto">
  <div className="px-3 py-2">
    <button onClick={() => setSidebarExpanded(!sidebarExpanded)}>
      <span className="sr-only">Expand / collapse sidebar</span>
      <svg className="w-6 h-6 fill-current sidebar-expanded:rotate-180" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path className="text-green-500" d="M19.586 11l-5-5L16 4.586 23.414 12 16 19.414 14.586 18l5-5H7v-2z" />
        <path className="text-green-500" d="M3 23H1V1h2z" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```